# Таймер в Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Можно ли как-нибудь сделать таймер в Firebase Firestore, чтобы через день после создания удалялась запись?

Comment: Только если у себя на серваке, используя sdk, периодически проверят время и удалять. Из коробки никакого ttl нет.